# Is there a secular concept of migu

Tags: words

I’ve been told by lawyers that there is no concept of migu in US secular law (loosely translated as believing someone because had he wanted to lie he could have said a better lie that would not have been questioned) Does the concept exist at all in the US or other societies ? For example a Kal Vchomer may not a American legal concept but the Latin word for it (a fortiori) does exist. What about migu?

Comment: I'm not sure that the US legal system has formal requirements for ne'emanus (and for that matter modern functioning batei din may also be more informal than halacha prescribes)

Comment: No, but "adverse inferences" is a legal concept that is the opposite of migu, whereby if a defendant failed to bring certain evidence that would have vindicated them, some will draw an "adverse inference" that in fact that evidence must have been damning for their case

Comment: What is the Judaism relevance of this question?

Comment: In my experience when trying to explain Migu or any other such concepts to secular Jewish professionals that I do Partners in Torah with, when they hear there is a similar secular concept they grasp it quicker.